# How to make MySQL to find old databases on HDD?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have reinstalled a MySQL 5.0instance to the same location (OS Windows XP), and afterwards, databases stored in `/data/` folder become invisible by MySQL. How I can to make it visible again ? All databases are MyISAM type.

Comment: If you had made no changes to the data directory and did not overwrite the `mysql` directory there, all your databases would be visible and accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the data directory setting in my.cnf to the location with all the data?

The variable you should be setting is `datadir = /path/to/data/directory`

You should probably restart the server once you have done that.